# What are dst and offset in timezone abbreviation when list with DateTimeZone::listAbbreviations()?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I have searched the web for the answer but don't succeed. And I know about UTC offset (for example +3:30 for Asia/Tehran). But I haven't figure out what are dst and offset in the list.

As an example, this key:

```
  ["tmt"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["dst"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["offset"]=>
      int(12344)
      ["timezone_id"]=>
      string(11) "Asia/Tehran"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["dst"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["offset"]=>
      int(5940)
      ["timezone_id"]=>
      string(14) "Europe/Tallinn"
    }
  }
```

shows that for Asia/Tehran (that UTC offset is +03:30 = 12600 and TMT corresponds to UTC offset +05) offset is 12344. How it is calculated? And what is that dst means?

Comment: @mickmackusa noted. Made it into an answer. Just needed time to make it more informative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual describes the result as:

> (an) associative array containing dst, offset and the timezone name

-- [Source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listabbreviations.php)

The keys in the output will be the timezone abbreviation (e.g. bst or gmt etc) and the values are all the timezones associated with that abbreviation.

The values have the format shared where:

- `dst` specifies whether daylight savings time is observed in that timezone. Meaning if once a year (e.g. in spring in the northern hemisphere) the time shifts by +1 hour and then reverts back about 6 months later.
- `offset` is the time (in seconds) that the timezone is away from UTC
- `timezone_id` is the string identifier of the locale which might correspond to the given timezone. (Timezone abbreviations are not unique)